# What to do with ambigious "Headers" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

[headers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/headers) is used both for HTTP headers and for `<head>` region. It does not have a wiki, so there is no canonical use. What should be done about it?

1. Leave it as is, provide wiki that describe both uses?
2. Decide on meta what should it be, then go thorough 28 tagged questions re-tagging them?
3. Delete it altogether as it's not constructive now?

If 2, what should it be about?

Answer (score 4):

My vote is to nuke it altogether.

[http-headers](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/http-headers) would be more appropriate a tag for http-header specific questions, and the concept of headers in an HTML page (whether that's `<head>` or HTML5 `<header>` tags) is too abstract to warrant its own tag here.

If this gets support I'll nuke it later on.

Comment: Sounds good for me, but I would seriously consider adding `html-headers`. I don't know if it's worth it, but tag `meta-tags` for meta information covers only part of head. (note: consider does not mean "I would do it", it just means consider; don't count it as my vote but as expression of doubt please)

Comment: @Mołot "meta-tags" would cause too much confusion with the Metatags module.

Comment: @Mołot Nitpicking, but `html-head` would be better - `html-headers` could be confused as another thing altogether (i.e. the `<header>` tag).

Comment: I don't care how would it be named. @MPD [`meta-tags`](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-tags) is not my idea, it exists already! used in 64 questions.

Answer (score 2):

Since the tag was used for two different purposes, I went ahead and removed it from the question using it.

Probably the same thing should be done for [footer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/footer). Even though the tag is used with a single purpose, probably it should be replaced with [regions](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/regions) or removed altogether. If the tag was used to mean `hook_footer()`, better tags would be [hooks](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hooks) and [hook-footer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/hook-footer).