# Rename "meta-tags" tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

> ["meta-tags" would cause too much confusion with the Metatags module](https://drupal.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2520/what-to-do-with-ambigious-headers-tag#comment-2082). – MPD♦

[meta-tags](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/meta-tags) is over a year old. If it's really confusing, it should be renamed, probably with an alias left under its original name.

Comment: MPD got upvoted for this in comment, I got downvoted for bringing this issue for discussion. Weird world.

Comment: Voting's a bit different on meta - downvotes aren't necessarily related to the quality of the post, more often than not they just imply disagreement with the suggestion (hence the lack of a distinct reputation system over here; stuff here is more opinion-based so it would be harsh to incur loss of reputation because of it. Meta.SO is a different story...). Similarly upvotes usually indicate agreement, and the lack of either implies a _meh, I'm easy either way_ :)

Answer (score 1):

[Meta tags](http://support.google.com/webmasters/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=79812) is the term that is usually used for those tags. The fact it is common for Drupal modules to adopt as name usual common doesn't mean the common term in Drupal mean the module. If all, a new tag should be used for the questions that are specific for the module, if necessity will be raised.

So far, we don't have [nodes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nodes) for questions about nodes, and [node.module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node.module) for the setting pages used by the Node module; in the same way, we don't have [views](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views) and [views.module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/views.module), or [feeds](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feeds) and [feeds.module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/feeds.module).
In Drupal there is always a module to handle an *entity*. Using [nodes](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/nodes) and [node.module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/node.module) would require to analyze the question and see if the question is about the setting pages provided by the module, or about the *entity* implemented by the module. (I am giving to *entity* a more generic meaning, not specific to Drupal.) It seems an arbitrary distinction, since a question about views is always a question about the Views module, and a question about nodes is always a question related to the Node module.

Having a tag for the module and a tag for the *entity* handled by the module would probably increase the confusion to users, who would not understand why there are two tags. I would also consider users already used to Stack Overflow's tags, where there isn't a tag for the Views module and a tag for views.